# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 randomly stops responding to PING

Tags: server, dhcp, ip, ping, hyper-v

So I have been having an issue with a new Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS.  I've re-installed the OS multiple times and it has the same problem.  I feel like I'm just missing something.  Any help you can provide would be very helpful!

**Issue**

I cannot ping my Ubuntu Server from my Windows Server 2012 R2 server UNLESS the Ubuntu server is first pinging it.  If I stop the ping from the Ubuntu Server, the ping fails on the Windows Server.

**Random thoughts/Notes**

1. This issue appears to be resolved when changing the Ubuntu Server to DHCP versus Static IP.
2. Disabling the firewall on both machines has no affect.
3. I am able to ping the Ubuntu server 100% of the time from a network switch as well as a Windows 10 Pro machine on the network.
4. Running `sudo apt update` && `sudo apt upgrade` fails when IP configuration is on static. DHCP succeeds.

...The windows server is the Hyper-V host that the Ubuntu VM is running on.